# How to add .aspx page in sharepoint 2010 project with visual studio 2012?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, asp.net, aspx

I went through following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312544/How-To-Add-Custom-ASP-NET-Page-Using-Layouts-Folde

http://sharepointsolution2010.blogspot.in/2011/05/add-custom-aspx-page-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Is this a right way to add .aspx page?

My requirement is to show custom list data into an .aspx page, that will require code behind to.

Alert email will have a link to open this .aspx page.

What is the right way to add .aspx page? as no direct option available in VS2012.

Comment: I have he problem in 2010 how to see the page. If I type the name I see the error 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure about Visual Studio 2012, but in Visual Studio 2008 & 2010, I had to modify "....csproj" and add a Projecttypes Guids for web projects to make this project web anf let me add ".aspx" or any other web related contents to project.

here's link to [few known ProjectTypeGuids](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added <PropertyGroup>
      
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup> but still not getting an option in "New Item" menu.

Comment: link I have given you was to different versions of VS but not to VS 2012 so I think you might have to find one yourself, by creating a web project then taking its webGuid :)

Comment: @timetothine my skype id is falaky :)

Comment: How add a site in 2010 Sharepoint ?

Answer (score 1):

I have an option in VS2012 to add an Application Page to the project. But it requires your project to be Farm Solution. Otherwise, you can't deploy to SharePoint hive (cause you need to place page to _layouts folder to have codebehind).

Also you can install [CKS DEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/releases/view/85955) to have more option for adding new items in SP project.

Comment: If you user sandbox solution you can create a web part and place it on pre configured page. In email notification you can point to this page url.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a Visual Web Part and deploy everything on a Web Part Page? Create a Web Part Page from SharePoint...

You can see here is explained the [difference between using a Web Part and Application Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/sharepoint-2010-application-pages-vs-web-parts)

You can achieve everything you need in a Visual Web Part, I hope this helps